# Cannot match the json array element to the value

Tags: spring, unit-testing, jsonpath

I want to make a unit test in spring boot. The case is that I have a JSON array and I have to check each array field "details" is equal to "T" or "S"(only "T" or "S" will be accepted). However, when I use Jsonpath & anyof. It gives me an assertion error, any solution can test it? thanks

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/hello"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$..records[*].abc.details",anyOf(is("T"),is("S"))))
}
```

This is the json

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "abc": {
        "details": "T",
        "create-date": "2016-08-24T09:36"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "abc": {
        "detail-type": "S",
        "create-date": "2012-08-27T19:31"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 64,
      "abc": {
        "detail-type": "S",
        "create-date": "2020-08-17T12:31"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: The picture shows the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you compare the strings `"T"` and `"S"` to a instance of JSONArray. Try out the following matcher:

```
MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath(
    "$..records[*].abc.details", 
    Matchers.anyOf(
        Matchers.hasItem("T"), 
        Matchers.hasItem("S")
    )
)
```

**UPDATE**:

according to your comment, you want your test to fail if `details` contain something else then `"T"` or `"S"`. Just pass another matcher to `jsonPath()`. [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/hamcrest-collections-arrays) you can find examples of matchers working with collections. In your particular case the matcher could look like this:

```
MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath(
    "$..records[*].abc.details", 
    Matchers.everyItem(
        Matchers.anyOf(
            Matchers.is("T"),
            Matchers.is("S")
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: If I not enter "T" or "S", it still can pass the unit test

Comment: @EdthinChung updated my answer. Just try out different matchers.